# Json4s seems to return quotes when dealing with strings, how can I force Json4s to just return the value?

Tags: json, scala, json4s

If I use something like:

`{company: {name: "Some Person"}}`

Then I use:

```
compact(render(json \ "company" \ "name"))
```

I would get back:

```
"Some Person"
```

Any way to just get back:

```
Some Person
```

without doing some substring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `extract`

```
scala> (json \ "company" \ "name").extract[String]
res4: String = Some Person
```

The necessary imports are

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
```

and in code

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
```

Comment: nice! the syntax just looks so strange to me and i couldnt find the correct method.